# In created application on Google's Developer Console How to create OAuth credentials?

Tags: google-apps-script, console

I try to install
https://github.com/JoeDawson/youtube pluging
which demands

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=YOUR_SECRET
```

parameters.
To get them I created an application on Google's Developer Console as :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/utMdY.jpg
Is it correct place new project ?
But I did not find how to create OAuth credentials
But I did not find where have I to create GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?
Is it correct editor just after I have registered myself at  Google's Developer Console and completed my Profile by filling questions by link
in confirmation email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check this [blog](https://theonetechnologies.com/blog/post/how-to-get-google-app-client-id-and-client-secret) on how to get Google app Client ID and Client Secret.

> 1. Login to Google Developer Console at https://console.developers.google.com using your google account credentials.
> 2. If you are not registered on Google developer account, then you need to accept agreement.
> 3. After accepting agreement or if you are already registered on Google developer account, you will see a screen as shown below. Click on “Select a project” on top header bar.
> 4. From the project selection popup click on the button with plus icon to add new project.
> 5. Enter your “Project name” and click on “Create” button.
> 6. It will open list page of API and Services. (you can also open this page from left side menu bar > “Library” menu)
> 7. From the list page search API with name “Google+ API” and click on the box with name “Google+ API”.
> 8. It will show the detail page of “Google+ API”, click on “Enable” button and it will return you back to dashboard.
> 9. From the dashboard click on “Credentials” from the left side menu.
> 10. From “Credentials” page click on “OAuth consent screen” tab and enter your website URL. Then click on “Save” button.
> 11. From the Credentials tab, click on “Create Credentials” dropdown and select “OAuth client ID”.
> 12. On OAuth client id creation screen:
>
>     - Select the “Web Application” radio button from the “Application Type”.
>     - Enter your application name in “Name” field. This name will be shown to end users when they are asked to give login permission to your website. So please specify meaningful name which can identify your website.
>     - Enter your catalog site URL in “Authorized JavaScript origins”. For example, if website domain is yourdomain.com, enter http://yourdomain.com
>     - In “Authorized redirect URIs” input box, enter your website URL + the page/end-point where you wanted your user redirected back. If you are using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google library, the end-point is “/signin-google”. For example, my website url is http://yourdomain.com, so I enter http://yourdomain.com/signin-google
>     - Click on “Create” Button.
> 13. It will display the popup with client id and client secret.

You may also follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) on how to use OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs.